# Does the "bat wing" aircraft paint design have a proper name?

Tags: terminology, paint

I would like to do a web search for different planes that have utilised the "bat wing" paint application noticeable on the wings below?  What keywords should I search for?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although aeroalias [is correct](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/32992/62) that this is often associated with Gee Bees, I think a more 'generic' term is a *scalloped* paint scheme, e.g.:

- [American Champion paint options](http://www.americanchampionaircraft.com/exterior-options.html)
- [C130 paint schemes](http://www.lockheedmartin.com/us/news/features/2015/C130PaintSchemes.html)
- [Model biplanes](http://griffwerks.com/biplane-kits.html)

Comment: Scalloped is the term I was looking for but I am still unable to find many aircraft images (other than Gee Bees).  In case is due to my unfamiliarity with aircraft terminology can I ask what search terms you used to return those results?

Comment: @darmi I think I simply searched for "scallop paint aircraft" or something similar, I can't remember exactly

Answer (score 7):

This particular paint scheme was used in a number of [Gee Bee aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granville_Brothers_Aircraft) (in different colors) and is popularly called the 'Gee Bee paint scheme'.

[image: Gee bee scheme]

GeeBee R2 Super Sportster By [Netweave](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Netweave) - Own work, [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=14492218)

According to the book [Gee Bee](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=X8oQCZvxYZ0C&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=Gee+Bee+paint+scheme&source=bl&ots=WpXhfzwY2I&sig=Zrz8hE6M9-wvUbWZrqomHCt1Sm4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ8b6DtZPQAhVHM48KHTdTDPMQ6AEIQzAJ#v=onepage&q=Gee%20Bee%20paint%20scheme&f=false):

> The Gee Bee's paint scheme was inspired by the Coca-Cola paint signs of the 1930s.

[This page](http://www.bowersflybaby.com/stories/altered.HTM), where an image similar (same?) as yours is available also calls it the Gee Bee scheme:

> Gee Bee paint schemes have been popular on Fly Babies, but have you ever wondered what one would look like with a small radial engine?